# Rewrite URL and remove part with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am really stuck with my .htaccess file, and need some help :). I have a WordPress installation that I am using for testing. It is in a folder and I use .htaccess to get there. This is the rules I use so far:

```
######### Custom #########
RewriteEngine On

# ignore folders
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "/af1wp/"
RewriteRule (.*) $1 [L]

###############
# only for me #
###############
# HOME (Senne Tijdeman)
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^###\.###\.###\.###$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^((www.)?([a-z0-9_\-]+).)?alleenf1.nl$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/af1wp/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /af1wp/$1 [L]
```

This works (with my real IP address of course), so no problem there. But now I want to rewrite exisiting URL's to a new format. The old URL is this:

http://alleenf1.nl/nieuws/QOgbb/raikkonen-alles-is-mogelijk-in-australi

The new URL should be this:

http://alleenf1.nl/raikkonen-alles-is-mogelijk-in-australi

The part I want to remove "**nieuws/QOgbb/**" is not always the same, so I have to use regex for that. But everything I tried did not work at all.

I thought this would be simple, but apparently not for me unfortunately. Now I have 2 questions.

1. What is the right RewriteRule to do this?
2. Where should I put it. In the .htaccess of the root folder, or the af1wp folder where the WordPress install is?

Tnx in advanced

---

To awnser the questions from **poncha** below:

1. Yes, the URL's always start with to folders. Just to clarify (was not clear) the part "nieuws" is always the same, but not the second part (call it an ID).
2. I prefer a redirect.
3. The file `/raikkonen-alles-is-mogelijk-in-australi` is a post in WordPress. That WordPress installation currently resides in the folder af1wp, but will be moved to the root folder when going live.

Comment: Please clarify a few points: does the original url always start with two "folders"? or maybe only the last portion (after the last slash) matters? also, should the browser be *redirected* to a new location, or perform sub-request (leaving the original url intact)? Does the file `/raikkonen-alles-is-mogelijk-in-australi` exist in document root, or is this virtual uri as well?

Comment: ^^ It would be better if you edit the question and provide the information i requested there, rather than responding in comments by the way.

Comment: @Poncha, tnx for your comment. I've updated the question for you :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^nieuws/([^/]+)/(.*) /af1wp/$1 [R=301,L,QSA]
```

1. This will only match URLs starting with "nieuws"
2. For now, the rewrite target is `/af1wp/`, change it to `/` when moving the wordpress.
3. When you move wordpress, you'll need to mix in this rule inside the wordpress rules, as it already has rewrite rules of its own - place this rule above its rules.
4. The flags used here:

   - `R=301` - redirect with HTTP status 301 (Moved Permanently).
   - `L` - last rule (stop rules parsing after successful match of this rule)
   - `QSA` - query-string-append (append original query string to the rewritten request).